# Expose FastAPI from EKS to external world with AWS Load Balancer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I have a FastAPI application deployed in EKS. It's currently listening on port 8000. It's running using uvicorn.
[image]

I'm trying to expose it externally by creating a classic load balancer from AWS by creating a Service within EKS.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bc-warrants-api-svc
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: bc-warrants-api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
```

When I checked the Load Balancer, it says the target instances are OutOfService.

I have a Django app, that is running perfectly fine (exposed externally through a classic load balancer).

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong with FastAPI?

[image]

Comment: I got it working now. I changed the app's port to port 80 and expose port 80 from the container. Updated the Service of type LoadBalancer, port and targetPort to 80.

Answer (score 0):

Check the healthcheck of the CLB. The culprit usually would be there. You can see what port and endpoint your CLB is performing the healthcheck on. Configure the healthcheck on the appropriate endpoint and the instance should be marked as healthy again.

Answer (score 0):

From seeing the screenshots, I assume that your **Uvicorn** is **listening** to **default** `host` and `port` which binds to `127.0.0.1` and port `8000`.

To make your application expose to the internet, you need to change the **default** `listen` **address** to `0.0.0.0`

```
$ uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
```

You can get more details here: https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/